# Google geolocation not taking all ajax parameter for address

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I'm creating an app for my own use. This app will take a column for address in spreadsheet in local machine and make ajax call to translate it into latitude and longitude. The problem I have now is, its not translating all addresses but only a few and the count varies every time I reload the page and check. Some returns null value when requested via ajax. But when I do it manually it does translate correctly. 
AM I doing this correctly, or is there better way doing

PHP

```
<?php
include 'excel_reader/excel_reader.php';     // include the class

// creates an object instance of the class, and read the excel file data
$excel = new PhpExcelReader;
$excel->read('test.xls');

// Excel file data is stored in $sheets property, an Array of worksheets
/*
The data is stored in 'cells' and the meta-data is stored in an array called 'cellsInfo'

Example (firt_sheet - index 0, second_sheet - index 1, ...):

$sheets[0]  -->  'cells'  -->  row --> column --> Interpreted value
         -->  'cellsInfo' --> row --> column --> 'type' (Can be 'date', 'number', or 'unknown')
                                            --> 'raw' (The raw data that Excel stores for that data cell)
*/

// this function creates and returns a HTML table with excel rows and columns data
// Parameter - array with excel worksheet data
function sheetData($sheet) {
  $re = '<table>';     // starts html table

  $x = 1;
  while($x <= $sheet['numRows']) {
    $re .= "<tr>\n";
    $y = 1;
    while($y <= $sheet['numCols']) {
      $cell = isset($sheet['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $sheet['cells'][$x][$y] : '';
      $re .= " <td class='sheet'>$cell</td>\n";  
      $y++;
    }  
    $re .= "</tr>\n";
    $x++;
  }

  return $re .'</table>';     // ends and returns the html table
}

$nr_sheets = count($excel->sheets);       // gets the number of sheets
$excel_data = '';              // to store the the html tables with data of each sheet

// traverses the number of sheets and sets html table with each sheet data in $excel_data
for($i=0; $i<$nr_sheets; $i++) {
  $excel_data .= '<h4>Sheet '. ($i + 1) .' (<em>'. $excel->boundsheets[$i]['name'] .'</em>)</h4>'. sheetData($excel->sheets[$i]) .'<br/>';  
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Example PHP Excel Reader</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}        
td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0 0.5em;
}        
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// displays tables with excel file data
echo $excel_data;
?>    
<div class='lat' style='background-color:#ff0;'></div>
<div class='lon' style='background-color:#0FF;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ajax request:

```
$(function(){

 $("td.sheet").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
     var address = $(this).text();
     var data;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "test.php?address="+address,
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        // console.log(data);
        for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++)
        {
            if($.trim(data[i].latitude)!= ""){
            $(".lat").append(data[i].latitude+" => location = "+data[i].location+"<br/>");
            }

            if($.trim(data[i].longitude)!= ""){
            $(".lon").append(data[i].longitude+" => location = "+data[i].location+"<br/>");
            }
        }
      }
    });
 });

});
```

Translating into lat and lon

```
$location = $_GET['address'];
//$location="Malaysia 11200";
/*..location coordinate starts*/
 $coordinates = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($location) . '&sensor=false');
    $coordinates = json_decode($coordinates);


    $lat = $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $lng = $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

$array = array();
array_push($array,array("latitude"=>$lat,"longitude"=>$lng,"location"=>$location));
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: This API has some usage limit, maybe that's why. Check what is returned when it fails. And i don't know how many `td.sheet` elements you are looping for but browser limit parallel requests too, maybe some are canceled

Comment: @A.Wolff, it returns null when fails.

Comment: Test if looping using a constant adress if it fails only sometimes

Comment: I tested 10 bunch , it returns all..maybe you're right..it has some limit to translate at one go

Comment: it only fails sometimes though

Comment: Does the JSON object have a status of "OK" for each request?

Comment: @Keren So ya i guess you are just reaching API usage limit. Just wondering, how many requests are you doing in a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a script in node.js and had it run 300 times. If it failed, I logged the JSON data. Here is what I got on the failed message.

```
{ error_message: 'You have exceeded your rate-limit for this API.',
results: [],
status: 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT' }
```

Looks like you were all right :)